# Can't import PyQt5

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

So I'm absolutely new to PyQt5 and apologize ahead.
Currently I'm trying to get this thing to work and now spent a good 5 hours or so trying to figure it out but I just can't. I pip installed PyQt5 systemwide but as soon as I try to run import the library I get an ImportError in the first line and a  ModuleNotFoundError in the second.[image]

Furthermore if I try to install PyQt5-tools everything goes absolutely nuts and I just can't figure out what is going wrong where and it's driving me insane.
[image]

Here are all the packages I have installed.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post code or debug as images, but as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name your own file something other than `PyQt5.py`. Python will first try to import things from the folder that you are currently in, so it will find your script `PyQt5.py`, which tells it to import `PyQt5.py`, which tells it to import... and so on. This is the reason that you get the hint "most likely due to a circular import".

Comment: There are no words that describe how thankfull I am!!! Thank you so much that was the problem! Now the only thing not working ist the PyQt5-tools install but thats not that bad. I just wanted to get started with something.

Comment: @Tobias2712 PyQt5 is not yet supported on Python 3.10. You either wait for that support to be restored, or you downgrade to Python 3.9.

Comment: @musicamante This is it, thank you so so much, finally everything works!